# How do I find the change in temperature in an ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, partition-function

I have to calculate the dependency of $\frac{\Delta T}{T}$ to $\frac{\Delta N}{N}$, within a gas that lose particles with energy $>E_0$ (in other words, I find the number of particles with energy $>E_0$ to get $\Delta N$). I've heard that the partition function contain all the information about the macro properties of the ensemble. So my question is that: in general, how do I find the temperature, and the change in temperature of an ensemble, say in this example, perhaps it's grand canonical? And how do I deduce that from the partition function?

Thank you :D

Comment: Can you express the dependence of $T$ on $N$?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find the change in T (the change in N can be found by M-B distribution). I think I'll add something to the question to make it clearer